# Trying to make a css3-only gallery. Failing miserably

Tags: html, css, gallery, pseudo-class

I'm trying to make an image gallery from scratch using only css3... And here's what I have so far.

[Here's an imgur album of my main three problems.](http://imgur.com/QbDDO9P&9hUIKmV&tCtaD0r)

1. The biggest problem is that I'm using position: relative so that I can align the image caption to the bottom. This is causing my images to reposition themselves once an image is clicked on.
2. The first image is off margin by like 5 pixels. I checked it using Chrome's Inspect Element tool, and there's no reason for this.
3. In codepen (and here), the images are super long. I suspect this isn't a real issue, but it looks a little wonky compared to my screenshots.

I tested it in safari and chrome, and these issues persist in both browsers (except number 3). Here's my code in progress:

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font: 400 14px/20px'PT Serif', serif;
  color: #2b2e2e;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
article {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav,
img,
header,
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
nav ul li {
  font: 12px/16px normal'Raleway', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
date {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 {
  font: 700 36px/40px'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
p {
  margin: 16px 0 20px 0;
}
ul,
ol {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 200%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
figure {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 0 3% 3% 0;
}
figcaption {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .25em 1em;
}
figure:first-of-type {
  width: 63%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
figure:focus {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out .5ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out .5ms;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out .5ms;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out .5ms;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample Article</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>

  <article>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>

          <li><a href="">Top</a>
            <ul>
              <li>Sub</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
            <ul>
              <li>Links</li>
              <li>Go</li>
              <li>Here</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Links</a>
            <ul>
              <li>And</li>
              <li>Here</li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </nav>

      <h1>Example Article Title</h1>
    </header>
    <figure tabindex=1>

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JdRTuQB.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Text goes here. Obviously there'll be more. Like this.</figcaption>

    </figure>
    <figure tabindex=2>

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/4PkhPlq.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Text goes here too</figcaption>

    </figure>
    <figure tabindex=3>

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kTcyEOe.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Some more captions</figcaption>

    </figure>
    <figure tabindex=4>

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mIeUOYX.jpg" />
      <figcaption>Almost done! Hehehe</figcaption>

    </figure>

  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EadOyL?editors=110

Comment: Cool gallery, what do you need help with removing the padding on the bottom?

Comment: Thanks! :) The problem is that the images move around once you click to enlarge one. Click on any image in the codepen for an example. Also there's an annoying margin (in the first picture on imgur) that I'm not sure how to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMS**

1. **Strange margin between header and first figure**
   There seems to occur when you use `inline-block` and dont add float direction.
   Fix: `float:left;`
2. **Image long or long image**
   This is caused by you setting: your figure to 30% and setting the child img to height 100%.
   That means that there the image is forced to all ways have full with and you set the width to auto. This results in a long image. My suggestion is simply setting a smaller fixed height so that more of the width of the image is shown. I used 90vh because it uses viewport measurements it scales good on mobile devices.
3. **Image moves out of order when I click image**
   First of all nice hack. `:focus` is not really a click now is it? focusing an element is what current element is selected. And on way of selecting it is with a click. Now since you use positon relative on the element and position absolute the element will not take up any space since that's what position absolute does.
   **tl;dr** : ...
   I added a div with class `fig-container` thats relative positioned and has the same height and width as the figure. And added a diffrent effect on the `:focus` i set the absolute positioned element (figure) with a top of 50% and left of 50% that makes the top left corner of the figure all ways be in the centre of the viewport. and added a transform translate of -50% x and -50% y `transform: transition(-50%, -50%);` this will move it to the centre of itself. In other words: centre that element.

**I WANT YOU TO CODE FOR ME:**
Fine here is the **[codepen](http://codepen.io/poi33/pen/yyRGoG)**

Comment: Hard to believe the answer was basically adding a <div> to each <figure>. Go figure. Heh thanks a ton mate! This was the easiest solution.